# Blank page when canceling payment transaction

Tags: cartthrob

I am experiencing a blank page after canceling a credit card payment offsite using Cartthrob and a built-in payment gateway. I see the page gets redirected to extload but just shows a blank screen. There are no issues when completing the transaction and get redirect to the correct page without any errors.

Working on the latest versions of the plugin and CMS so that could not be the issue, maybe there is something I have missed in the setup?

Comment: When you have the blank screen and the redirections stop, is the url like example.com/themes/third_party/cartthrob/libs/extload.php?

Comment: Which payment gateway is it? It's probably due to an issue where the gateway itself isn't set to handle a cancellation. If I know what gateway it is, we could probably make sure a method to handle cancellations is included.

Comment: Hi Chris, it is the Netcash gateway. It also does not show the a custom error page on the website. I can setup a support call through the website if this is easier.